# How to rename the original files of scripts in index.html using gulp?

Tags: javascript, caching, build, gulp

I've written a gulp task to rename files so that they can be versioned. The problem is that the filenames of the files that the `index.html` scripts reference are not changed.

For example, in my `index.html`:

```
<script src=pub/main_v1.js"></script>
```

But if you actually navigate through the build folder to the subdirectory `pub`, you will find `main.js`.

Here is the custom gulp task:

```
const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
const gulpReplace = require('gulp-replace');
const version = require('./package.json').version;

gulp.task('version', function () {
    var vsn = '_' + version + '.js';
    gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulpConcat(vsn))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./prodBuild'));

    return gulp.src('./prodBuild/index.html', { base: './prodBuild' })
        .pipe(gulpReplace(/* some regex */, /* append vsn */))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./prodBuild'));
});
```

What do I need to fix/add so that the original filename changes to match that in the script tag?

Note: According to the gulp-concat [docs](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat), I should be able to find the concated files at `prodBuild/[vsn]`, where `[vsn]` is `_v1.js`. However, it is no where to be found.

**Update:** The files rename properly in `index.html`, but I can't seem to get the renaming of the original files to work. Here's a snapshot of my build directory:

```
prodBuild/
 pub/
   main.js
 someDir/
   subDirA/
     // unimportant stuff
   subDirB/
     file2.js
   file3.js
 // ...other files and folders...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The issue is that you return only one of the two tasks. The first task is simply ignored by gulp, since it is not returned. A simple solutions: Split it into two tasks, and reference the one from the other, like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236314/gulpjs-combine-two-tasks-into-a-single-task#24238972).

**Old Answer**

This looks like a perfect case for the [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename). You could simply pipe your scripts through `gulp-rename`, like this:

```
.pipe(rename(function (path) {
    path.basename += vsn;
    path.extname = ".js"
  }))
```

Gulp concat is, AFAIK, made for the concatination of *files*, not particularly for the renaming of them.

Comment: where would this go in my gulp task?

Comment: Nvm, I see now that this *should* also just work with gulp-concat :) Could you add a full directory structure of what you're seeing before and after building with that gulp script to your question? Because I think we need more information to find the source of the problem causing this

Comment: Could you explain how it *should* be working with gulp-concat? My understanding is that gulp-concat should help with the renaming. However, that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: See my updated answer - I think the issue lies completely elsewhere :)

Comment: thanks for your help so far! regarding your edit, should the concat task come first?

Comment: The order should not matter, as they touch different files. You can pick either one to go first, arbitrarily.