# run npm script using gulp got repeated action

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I saw multiple repeated execution of my node script when I try to chain and run my npm script in gulp. Below is my gulp file.

```
gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src( base + 'icons/*.svg' )
        .pipe($.iconfontCss({
            targetPath  : "../css/myicons.css",
            fontPath    : '../fonts/',
            cssClass    : 'sa-icon',
        }))
        .pipe($.iconfont({
            formats     : ['svg', ],
            timestamp   : Math.round(Date.now()/1000),
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( dist.fonts ))
        .pipe(run('npm run icons-to-json')); 
});
```

My node script, there's nothing wrong with it for sure, I tried node icons-to-json it worked just fine, don't have repeated action.

```
const iconsFolder = './icons';
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

    let json = [];
    fs.readdir(iconsFolder, [], (err, files) => {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if(file.split('.')[0] !== 'icons'){
            json.push({'name': file.split('.')[0]})
        }
      });
      jsonfile.writeFile(iconsFolder+'/icons.json' , json);
    });
```

My terminal look like this when I run `gulp icons`

```
[12:11:23] Using gulpfile ~\Projects\my-web\gulpfile.js
[12:11:23] Starting 'icons'...
[12:11:23] gulp-svgicons2svgfont: Font created
$ npm run icons-to-json

> @ icons-to-json C:\Users\Superant-Laptop\Projects\my-web\
> node icons-to-json

$ npm run icons-to-json

> @ icons-to-json C:\Users\Superant-Laptop\Projects\my-web\
> node icons-to-json

$ npm run icons-to-json

> @ icons-to-json C:\Users\Superant-Laptop\Projects\my-web
> node icons-to-json

$ npm run icons-to-json

> @ icons-to-json C:\Users\Superant-Laptop\Projects\my-web
> node icons-to-json

[12:11:33] Finished 'icons' after 9.97 s
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running `npm run icons-to-json` for every svg icon you have in `base + 'icons/`.

If you only want that to run once, you need to follow the pattern as shown here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

That is, the first stream processes all icons and the next stream runs an npm script - merge both of those streams and you have one task.

The alternative is to run the second stream as a separate task which runs only after first task of processing icons is done.

**Update:**

Here are some examples of patterns like the first I mentioned:

[Gulpjs combine two tasks into a single task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236314/gulpjs-combine-two-tasks-into-a-single-task)

Here is an example of the second approach:

```
gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src( base + 'icons/*.svg' )
        .pipe($.iconfontCss({
            targetPath  : "../css/myicons.css",
            fontPath    : '../fonts/',
            cssClass    : 'sa-icon',
        }))
        .pipe($.iconfont({
            formats     : ['svg', ],
            timestamp   : Math.round(Date.now()/1000),
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( dist.fonts ));
});

gulp.task('icons-to-json', function() {
  return run('npm run icons-to-json').exec();
});

gulp.task('icons-tasks', function() {
  gulp.start('icons', 'icons-to-json');
});
```

Comment: I think what I need is just run icons-to-json after the icons task.

Comment: I would prefer that as well if I were in your situation.  Please accept my answer if you think it answered what you asked for.  Thanks!

Comment: add the code it, I still haven't found any working solution yet, you gave me hint not answer.

Comment: there's no relation btw icons task and npm task? You should put it in all. What if I just want to run icons task but i have other tasks besides these 2?

Comment: I changed the code to make it more obvious what is going on.  The relationship that icons and icons-to-json tasks have to each other is defined in the icons-tasks.
In short, you can run icons task by itself, you could run icons-to-json task by itself, or you could run both by running the icons-tasks task.

This last task could be run as a part of a bigger task that runs other tasks besides these two.